# How does the Stack Overflow ask question work?

Tags: support, asking-questions, login, sign-up

When will you ask me to log in?

Comment: You don't need to create an account, though it is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

you might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/faq first.

> Do I have to log in or create an
>   account?
>
> Nope. You can answer and ask questions
>   to your heart’s content as an
>   anonymous user, much like Wikipedia.
>   However, there are some things you
>   won’t be able to do on the site
>   without registering. But it’s easy to
>   register if you want to. All you need
>   is an OpenID.

You don't need to register if you want but when you have an account you will have so much more privileges depends on your activity and behaviour on the site